# Query by method calculated parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am implementing a search funcionality in a table on the screen.
This table has some calculated fields, but I must be able to search by all fields in it.
Since the request must be paginated, I am performing the filtering, ordering, pagination, etc in the backend using JPA and Spring Data.
The calculations are too complex to be calculated using hibernate @Formula annotation.

My actual solution was to insert the calculated values together in the database so I can use the fields in the query. But I don't know if this is the best approach, since I end up with some unecessary data stored.

Is there another way to perform this kind of queries with JPA/Hibernate? Or a better tool to do such thing?

Comment: Storing calculated data in the database to simplify querying and boosting performance is usually a good idea.

Comment: Does the fields required for calculation change based on some condition or is is same each time?. If the fields don't change dynamically then just perform the calculation once and store it in database and read it everytime. But if the fields change dynamically, then perform the calculatio  on getting the first request and store in cache or database and then read it next time before calculating

Comment: @pvpkiran The calculations are based on a set of entities, each time they change, the calculation must be done again. I used the @@PreUpdate and @@PrePersist JPA anotations for this